# How can I download all artifacts for appended builds in Artifactory?

Tags: devops, artifactory

I’m trying to figure how to use Artifactory in a rather complicated build setup. We have several build machines doing multi hour builds of several components from the same code base.

I want Artifactory to consider all the artifacts resulting from one git hash to be one build, even if these were produced by several build machines. I also want to run tests on the build later and append test results to this build. And in the end, promote builds and download their artifacts.

My question is, how can this be achieved using the build integration feature in Artifactory?

I have tried the recent build append feature, which sounds perfect from the little documentation available. It can create a new aggregated build, consisting of several existing published builds. However, I can’t figure out how to use the aggregated build to anything useful (like downloading the aggregated artifacts), or am I missing something?

What is the intended purpose of the build append feature, if not what I’m after?

Comment: We are planning to enhance the new aggregated build-info entity and allow downloading the artifacts of all the appended builds. This is planned to be introduced in the near future.

Comment: We support hosting metadata for artifacts on Reliza Hub - https://relizahub.com - if you don't mind another tool. It has capability to bundle builds and use it in various CI/CD contexts.

Comment: Thanks @EyalBenMoshe 
Do you have a roadmap showing what you intend to do with this feature? That would be very helpful for our choice of platform.

Comment: Will checkout relizahub.com too. Thanks!

Comment: We are going to launch this functionality during the next few weeks. The "jfrog rt dl" command already accepts the --build option, which allows downloading artifacts by their build. This option will soon allow downloading the artifacts of all aggregated builds, referenced by the build-info recursively.

Comment: That sounds great! Will that work with promotion too?

Comment: Please add support for promotion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The downloading from appended build feature is available since JFrog CLI 1.45.0.

All new functionality is transparent to the user. To download the build artifacts, run `jfrog rt dl --build=<buildName>/<buildNumber>`. If the build has an aggregated build, the aggregated build's artifacts will be downloaded too.

This is available for all JFrog CLI remote artifacts commands: Search, Download, Delete, Move, Copy, etc.

Usage example:

```sh
# Create and publish build a/1
jfrog rt upload foo.zip generic-local --build-name a --build-number 1
jfrog rt build-publish a 1

# Create build b/1
jfrog rt upload bar.zip generic-local --build-name b --build-number 1

# Append published build a/1 to b/1
jfrog rt build-append b 1 a 1

# Publish b 1
jfrog rt build-publish b 1

# Download foo.zip and bar.zip
jfrog rt download --build=b/1
```

Read more [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-AggregatingPublishedBuilds).

Comment: Hi! While this works, it's not really useful as build promotion currently doesn't promote aggregated builds. So if you want to use build promotion, you still have to add extra logic to find all aggregated builds and promote them separately. Do you have any plans to support aggregated promotion?

Comment: @arvidr I'm not sure I understand your use case. You may have 2 builds in 2 repositories. Currently, you can promote build from repo A to repo B. What, in this case, will be the target repository of the second build artifacts?

Comment: My typical use case is as follows:
1. We start one top-level build of a specific Git hash
2. The top-level builder spawns builders on Windows, macOS and Linux. Possibly multiple builders per OS
3. The individual builders finish their work and upload the artifacts to the same repository, but using individual build numbers.
4. The top-level builder appends all the sub-builds into one buildname/buildnumber

This is all great! Our QA can use the top-level build to download all files etc. and we can refer to this build, and potential release, using the buildname/buildnumber as an unique ID.

Comment: However, we can’t promote the top-level build to the staging repository, as that won’t move any files. We need to promote all the sub builds individual, which requires manual work or scripting, and sort of limits the usefulness of the aggregated builds. I think it would make a lot of sense if aggregated builds could be managed in the same way as others builds, with respect to promotion for example.